# write string continously using fprintf

Tags: c++, opencv, arduino

My project is tracking object using opencv and send the coordinate to arduino as tx and read the data using another arduino (rx) with 'SoftwareSerial'. There are no problem with object tracking, knowing the coordinate, and communication between 2 arduino. The problem is i can not send the coordinate while 'tracker' running, but when I close the 'tracker', the data start appearing in the serial com.

opencv code

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

//default capture width and height
int FRAME_WIDTH = 320; //640 320
int FRAME_HEIGHT = 240; //480 240

int MIN_OBJECT_AREA = 10*10;

int iLowH = 16;
int iHighH = 104;

int iLowS = 110; 
int iHighS = 164;

int iLowV = 63;
int iHighV = 255;

int centerX, centerY;
int Xg,Yg;

int Modefilter = 1;

FILE *fp;
bool kirim=false;

string intToString(int number){


    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

void detect(){

}

int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    //open serial
    FILE* serial = fopen("\\\\.\\COM3", "w+");
    if (serial == 0) {
        printf("Failed to open serial port\n");
    }


    //capture the video from web cam
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // if not success, exit program
    if ( !cap.isOpened() ){  
        cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //set height and width of capture frame
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_WIDTH);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_HEIGHT);

    //create a window called "Control"
    namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    //Create trackbars in "Control" window

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowH", "Control", &iLowH, 179); //Hue (0 - 179)
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighH", "Control", &iHighH, 179);

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowS", "Control", &iLowS, 255); //Saturation (0 - 255)
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighS", "Control", &iHighS, 255);

    cvCreateTrackbar("LowV", "Control", &iLowV, 255); //Value (0 - 255)
    cvCreateTrackbar("HighV", "Control", &iHighV, 255);


    string XX,YY,parser1,parser2,result;

    while (serial!=0){

        Mat imgOriginal;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess){ //if not success, break loop
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
            break;
        }

        //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV
        Mat imgHSV;
        cvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, COLOR_BGR2HSV); 

        //find center point
        centerX = FRAME_WIDTH/2;
        centerY = FRAME_HEIGHT/2;

        putText(imgOriginal, "Tekan", Point(5,10), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.35, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 0.25, 8);
        putText(imgOriginal, "a : Mulai Mengikuti Objek", Point(5,20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.35, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 0.25, 8);
        putText(imgOriginal, "b : Berhenti Mengikuti Objek", Point(5,30), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.35, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 0.25, 8);

        //create cross line
        line(imgOriginal,Point(centerX, centerY-20), Point(centerX, centerY+20), Scalar(0,255,0), 1.5);
        line(imgOriginal,Point(centerX-20, centerY), Point(centerX+20, centerY), Scalar(0,255,0), 1.5);

        //Threshold the image
        Mat imgThresholded;

        inRange(imgHSV, Scalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV), Scalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV), imgThresholded);

        //morphological opening (remove small objects from the foreground)
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );
        dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 

        //morphological closing (fill small holes in the foreground)
        dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) ); 
        erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5)) );

        //these two vectors needed for output of findContours
        vector< vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

        Mat imgContour;
        imgThresholded.copyTo(imgContour);

        //find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
        findContours(imgContour,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

        //use moments method to find our filtered object
        double refArea = 0;
        if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
            int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
            for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {
                Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
                double area = moment.m00;
                if(area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA){ //jika area kontur lebih besar dari minimum area object maka gambar lingkaran dan tulis koordinat
                    kirim=true;
                    double x = moment.m10/area;
                    double y = moment.m01/area;
                    double r = sqrt(area/3.14);

                    Xg=(int) x;
                    Yg=(int) y;

                    circle(imgOriginal, Point(x,y), r, Scalar(0,0,255), 1.5, 8);

                    line(imgOriginal, Point(x,y-r-5), Point(x,y+r+5), Scalar(0,0,255), 1.5, 8);
                    line(imgOriginal, Point(x-r-5,y), Point(x+r+5,y), Scalar(0,0,255), 1.5, 8);

                    putText(imgOriginal, intToString(x) + "," + intToString(y), Point(x,y+10), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.25, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 0.3, 8);

                    // send x,y coordinate to arduino
                    parser1="*"; parser2="!";
                    ostringstream xxx,yyy ;
                    xxx << Xg;
                    yyy << Yg;
                    XX=xxx.str(); YY=yyy.str();
                    result=parser1+XX+parser2+YY;

                    cout << result << endl; 

                    fprintf(serial, "%s\n", result.c_str());    
                    fflush(serial);         

                }//end if
            }//end for
        }//end if


        //show the thresholded image
        Mat dstimgThresholded;
        resize(imgThresholded, dstimgThresholded, Size(), 2, 2, INTER_CUBIC);
        imshow("Thresholded Image", dstimgThresholded);

        //show the original image 
        Mat dstimgOriginal;
        resize(imgOriginal, dstimgOriginal, Size(), 2, 2, INTER_CUBIC);
        imshow("Original", dstimgOriginal);     

        ///send data        

        if (waitKey(5) == 27) {//wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }

    } //end while

    return 0;

}
```

tx arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SWsend(2, 3); // (rx,tx)

String data;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SWsend.begin(4800);
  //pinMode(12,INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void Send_SSIDandPWD_ToESP01() {
  while (!SWsend) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect.
    Serial.println(F("wait for serial port to connect."));
  }
  while (Serial.available()) {
    data = Serial.readString();
    //data = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(F("Send:"));
    Serial.println(data);
    SWsend.print(data);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Send_SSIDandPWD_ToESP01();
  delay(25);
}
```

rx arduino

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SWrecv(2, 3); //(rx,tx)
String strSSID = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
String strPWD = "";
bool keepSSID = false;
bool keepPWD = false;
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SWrecv.begin(4800);

  // Turn on the blacklight and print a message.

  Serial.println(F("Hello, world!"));
}

void loop() {
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  SWrecvEvent();
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println("X:" + strSSID  + ", Y:" + strPWD);
    // clear the string:
    //  inputString = "";
    if (strSSID == "")
    {
      Serial.println("SSID:not config");
    }
    strSSID = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
    strPWD = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

void SWrecvEvent() {
  while (SWrecv.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)SWrecv.read();
    //Serial.print(inChar); ///////////////////string asli
    // add it to the inputString:
    switch (inChar ) {
      case '*':
        {
          keepSSID = true;
          keepPWD = false;
        }
        break;
      case '!':
        {
          keepSSID = false;
          keepPWD = true;
        }
        break;
      default:
        {
          if (inChar == '\n') {
            stringComplete = true;
            keepSSID = false;
            keepPWD = false;
            return;
          }
          if (keepSSID == true )
          {
            strSSID += inChar;
          }
          else if (  keepPWD == true )
          {
            strPWD += inChar;
          }
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

what should I do to write coordinate countinously while the tracker is running?

Comment: add thread that will be responsible for sending the data ?

Comment: sorry? i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the IO is being buffered, and only flushed when you exit your tx program.  Try calling [Flush](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush) to force the data to send.

Comment: I add `fflush(serial);` after `fprint`, it send data when the detected object out of frame (without close porgram). but still, i want to send the data while detected object on frame.